# Omitting ground pour on top in a 4 layer pcb, but IC manufacturer recommends it?

Tags: ground, grounding

So I am working on a board which have an IC from manufacturer Murata [SCHA63T](https://www.murata.com/en-global/products/sensor/gyro/overview/lineup/scha63t)

The datasheet is a little bit vague about the recommended PCB design, but they offer a small evaluation board which I have studied: [Eval Board](https://www.murata.com/-/media/webrenewal/products/sensor/pdf/specification/scha600-series-chip-carrier-pcb-specification.ashx?la=en&cvid=20210927070126000000)

So there, they poured the entire top layer for GND. I would omit this and use an inner GND layer in my 4 layer design. I would ground the pins with close vias.

Would it cause problem? Or should I follow the eval board design?

Links: 
[SCHA63T datasheet](https://www.murata.com/-/media/webrenewal/products/sensor/pdf/datasheet/scha63t-k03_datasheet_short.ashx?la=en&cvid=20210302025355000000)

[SCHA63T EvalBoard datasheet](https://www.murata.com/-/media/webrenewal/products/sensor/pdf/specification/scha600_series_chip-carrier_pcb_specification.ashx?la=en&cvid=20210302030225000000)

Comment: Please link the pdf data sheet.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is fine. They poured the entire top layer because they wanted a good ground. Grounds are better when they are continuous because return currents can flow directly back to their source and because it generally lowers resistance (traces have much more resistance than a plane).

Sometimes on RF boards you need to do a pour on the top layer, this part doesn't operate in those frequencies (and it looks like it has shielding built into the part) so you could neglect the top copper pour, or you could leave it.